# Cannot re-render Blazor components that are generated by foreach

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a componet that contains a list of posts. I want to delete some posts. my problem is that the removed posts does not removed on the screen, even when I use `StateHasChanged()`.

Here is `PostListComponent.razor` file

```razor
@if (PostsList != null)
{
    foreach (var post in PostsList)
    {
        if(post.IsDeleted != true)
        {
         <div>
          <span @onclick="@(()=>DeletePost(post.PostId))" class="oi oi-trash" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
          <p>post.Content</p>
         </div>
        }
     }
}
```

and `PostListComponent.cs` :

```cs
public partial class PostListComponent : ComponentBase
{

 [Parameter]
 public List<PostContent> PostsList { get; set; }    

 protected void DeletePost(string postId)
 {
    PostsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == postId).IsDeleted=true;
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
 }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    DBContext _db;
    _db = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
    PostsList = _db.Posts.Where(s => (s.IsDeleted != true).ToList();

  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to call StateHasChanged(). The correct answer has already been given by @MrC. Ask him to post it as an answer here. Note: Your code is fine. Change div to button, and add some text for title. That is all you need to alter.

Comment: @enet yes the code works fine as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components)], using the `@key` directive is required for rendering a list of elements or components and the elements or components subsequently change.

Using `@key` directive solve the problem.

Here is the code:

```
@if (PostsList != null)
{
    foreach (var post in PostsList)
    {
        if(post.IsDeleted != true)
        {
         <div @key="post">
          <span @onclick="@(()=>DeletePost(post.PostId))" class="oi oi-trash" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
          <p>post.Content</p>
         </div>
        }
     }
}
```

I would like to appreciate [Brian Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492496/brian-parker) for his comment on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project to replicate your code on my side to troubleshoot the issue. However, it works as **enet** mentioned.

Did some slight changes including correcting the statement below:

```
// Cannot resolve symbol 'ToList'
PostsList = _db.Posts.Where(s => (s.IsDeleted != true).ToList();
```

Overall, it works.

Here is my result:

```razor
@page "/"

@if (PostsList != null)
{
    foreach (var post in PostsList)
    {
        if(post.IsDeleted != true)
        {
         <div>
          <button @onclick="@(()=>DeletePost(post.PostId))" class="oi oi-trash" style="cursor: pointer;"></button>
          <p>@post.Content</p>
         </div>
        }
     }
}
```

```cs
public partial class Index : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public List<PostContent> PostsList { get; set; }
    
    [Inject]
    public ApplicationDbContext dbContext { get; set; }

    protected void DeletePost(string postId)
    {
        PostsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == postId).IsDeleted = true;
        //InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PostsList = dbContext.Posts.Where(s => (s.IsDeleted != true)).ToList();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class PostContent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

[image: animation]